# Laravel, simplifying two Eloquent queries into one

Tags: php, laravel

Can i simplify this two queries into one, i have my versions which works but i think it can be done more simpler

```
public function removeFriend($userId)
{
   $user = User::findOrFail($userId);
   $user_id = $user->id;

   $me = \Auth::user();
   $me_id = $me->id;


   //DB::table('friends')->where(['friend_id' => $me_id, 'user_id' => $user_id, 'accepted' => '1'])->delete();
   //DB::table('friends')->where(['friend_id' => $user_id, 'user_id' => $me_id, 'accepted' => '1'])->delete();

   //$first = DB::table('friends')->where(['friend_id' => $me_id, 'user_id' => $user_id, 'accepted' => '1']);
   //DB::table('friends')->where(['friend_id' => $user_id, 'user_id' => $me_id, 'accepted' => '1'])->union($first)->delete();



   return redirect()->back();
}
```

commented lines are the two queries, below is the one that i researched but ithink its kinda same thing, basically i tried to join second query with orWhere(), but it gets all other friends too, and if i join them with only where() it doesn't get anything so that's a bust

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question I am assuming you want to implement "Unfriend" feature.

Let's just update your code.

```
public function removeFriend($userId)
{
    // This is not necessary. You are making one more query which is doing nothing basically. You are getting $userID which is same as $user->id
    //$user = User::findOrFail($userId);
    //$user_id = $user->id;

    //DB::table('friends')->where(['friend_id' => $me_id, 'user_id' => $user_id, 'accepted' => '1'])->delete();
    //DB::table('friends')->where(['friend_id' => $user_id, 'user_id' => $me_id, 'accepted' => '1'])->delete();

    //$first = DB::table('friends')->where(['friend_id' => $me_id, 'user_id' => $user_id, 'accepted' => '1']);
    //DB::table('friends')->where(['friend_id' => $user_id, 'user_id' => $me_id, 'accepted' => '1'])->union($first)->delete();

    // Better Approach
    try {
        $result DB::table('friends')
            ->where(function($query) use($userID) {
                $query->where('friend_id', $userID)->where('user_id', Auth::id());    
            })->orWhere(function($query) use($userID) {
                $query->where('user_id', $userID)->where('friend_id', Auth::id());
            })
            ->delete();

        //Do whatever you want woth result
    }
    catch(/Exception $e) {
        // Exception Handling;
    }          

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

***Note: Not Tested.***

Comment: thanks for the tip for userID, but solution didn't work it got with second orWhere() statement it got other friends too

Comment: @JamesAmbardnishvili I just updated code. Now, can you try and let me if it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

For you to be building the queries that way means your ids are indeed different. If such is the case, you can use the `orWhere` as an advanced query to add both values and get 2 rows that you can cycle and delete. But because they are different you will never have 2 rows merged into 1 and be able to use delete like that. It does not come out as an object when you start joining things:

```
Friend::where('accepted', '=' 1)->where( function($query) use($me_id, $user_id) {
                                      $query->where('friend_id', '=', $user_id)
                                            ->orWhere('friend_id', '=', $me_id);
                                 })->get();
```

Comment: this one didn't work either, thanks for the response though

Comment: @JamesAmbardnishvili thank you for your feedback! If you share the error it gave I might be able to help further, unless you reached the place you desired :)